# Shiny server Install CentOS 8.1 build

Tags: r, shiny, centos8

I am attempting to do a fresh build of a Shiny server, using CentOS 8. I have been using the instructions on the Shiny server download site.
I have been successful up to the point of installing the Shiny R packages. Using the code on the website

```
sudo su -
-c "R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"">
I am getting the following error/response: <[root@CP-Shiny]# sudo su - \ -c "R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')""
su: user -c does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

It escapes the quotes inside quotes using `\`

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the command above, now I am getting the following response:     bash: R: command not found

Comment: That probably means R is not installed

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  But R is installed.  I think the reason we are getting command not found is because using sudo su - puts you in root environment which doesn't have R in its path.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.  Andrew's method didn't work despite R being installed, since `sudo su` - puts you in root environment and the PATH to R isn't available.  I suppose you could try the full path to R and see if that works.  However, I used a different method, and did a

```
sudo /opt/R/4.3.1/bin/R #need the full path
```

then within the R session I did:

```
install.packages("shiny")
```

This seems to have worked and I was able to subsequently install shiny server using the `sudo yum`.